# What do these weird symbols mean in js?

Tags: javascript

It comes from an if statement they use es6 but never seen '/#' being used. Anyone care to explain. (note the backtick is remove from stackflow )

Here is the snippet of code: 
https://codedump.io/share/LPW9jWNDJZwl/1/weird-javascript
Here is package.json if it can help: https://codedump.io/share/HlvwlcmeiPW9/1/packagejson

```
    // Flash around where you have just spawned
    if (`/#${this.socket.id}` === player.id &&
            player.moveCounter <= ClientConfig.TURNS_TO_FLASH_AFTER_SPAWN &&
            player.moveCounter % 2 === 0) {
        this.canvasView.drawSquareAround(player.segments[0], ClientConfig.SPAWN_FLASH_COLOR);
    }

    if (player.base64Image) {
        this.canvasView.drawImages(player.segments, player.base64Image);
    } else {
        this.canvasView.drawSquares(player.segments, player.color);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `/#` in the template string is nothing special, it means literally those characters. It might become more clear if you read up on ES6 template strings.

Answer (score -1):

Backticks are [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). In this case,

`` `/#${this.socket.id}` `` becomes the string `"/#1"` assuming the value for `this.socket.id` is 1.